# module.js:540 Error: Cannot find module 'semver'

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, module, node-modules

Getting error me but, it not resolve any npm command when i enter **npm** command.
It showing below error in image. How can i resolve it. i tried to unistall and remove through command line but showing below error please help me. I'm stuck in [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJcPV.jpg)this process

Please help me and i also tried mannualy uninstall and reinstall process node.js after that also getting this error.

Answer (score -1):

Remove all globally installed npm packages.
From folder
 **C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm**
You can get here quickly by typing %appdata% (either in explorer, run prompt, or start menu).